# Checking type and number of an Object

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code in which the below `condition` is being check, canyone tell me why would one want to skip for this condition?.

```
    var number = /^\d+$/;
    var type = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj);

    for(var key in obj) {
        if(type === '[object String]' && number.test(key)) {
           continue; //Why is this condition skipped
        }
       //some other code
    }
```

Below is the sample `object` i am passing to the `function`.

```
{a: {someotherObject: {games: ['12']}}}
```

**Update:**

When would the above condition satisfy, which it would skip? I am interested on what json  if pass, would that condition match?.

Comment: What is `type`? What is `number`?

Comment: If the condition is fulfilled then `//some other code` does not execute. `continue` jumps you out of the current iteration of the loop and into the next one.

Comment: @Madbreaks—it's nice to have working code so broad assumptions aren't made. Maybe the condition is skipped because it always evaluates to false? Maybe it's throwing an error that the OP isn't seeing?

Comment: The value of the *a* property is an Object (*type* is '[object Object]'), not a String, so the if test will be false and the `continue` statement will not be executed. If you passed it `obj.a.someotherObject.games[0]` (i.e. the string '12') it might "work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When would the above condition satisfy,

It will be true when *obj* is a String object and *key* is a value like '12'. In the OP, *obj* is an Object so the test fails at `type === '[object String]'`

> which it would skip?

Whenever *type* is not *'[object String]'* or the key is not just digits. A value that will pass is a string like '12' or '12345' or '0'.

> I am interested on what json if pass, would that condition match?.

I have no idea what that means. :-(

If *obj* is a value like '12', then in the expression:

```
for (var key in obj)
```

*obj* is temporarily converted to an object as if by `new String(obj)` (the String constructor is used because the Type of *obj* is string). This object has two "keys": '0' and '1' whose properties are '1' and '2' respectively. So the test:

```
if (type === '[object String]' && number.test(key))
```

is true because the object is a String and its keys are numbers. There are no non–numeric, enumerable keys so the *continue* statement will mean nothing happens in the loop. e.g.

```
var obj = '12';
var type = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj); 
var number = /^\d+$/;

for (var key in obj) {

    // This will be true for both keys
    if (type === '[object String]' && number.test(key)) {
       console.log(key);   // 1, 2
       continue;
    }
   //some other code
}
```

If *obj* is anything other than a String, "some other code" will execute.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob, This line really made me understood... "obj is temporarily converted to an object as if by new String(obj) "

Answer (score 1):

The idea of that loop is to "pass" on those entries that match the `if` condition (perhaps leaving as-is), and to take some action (`//some other code`) when an entry is encountered that doesn't meet that condition.